# String to byte convertion in java

Tags: java, parsing, byte

i m new in java....i m trying to read a text file using file input stream. i m reading text line by line and set as a string.. now i want to convert string into byte. but i m getting a number format exception.. please help me to solve this problem.

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/data.txt");

          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          byte[] bytes = null;
          String str;
          int i=0;

          while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) 
          {

              bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(str,16);
              i++;
          }

          in.close();
```

Comment: Make sure that your `str` contains the value that can be parsed into bytes. For e.g., you cannot of course parse "abc" into a byte value right? For that you would need to use - `"abc".getBytes()`

Comment: do you need 2D array of bytes actually? or you will use array of bytes temporary for every string?

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
```

instead of

```
bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(str,16);
```

Also I recommend to specify encoding for InputStreamReader:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

Keep in mind that Java String length and internal representation would not be same to C.

Comment: i tried this. i want to store each byte values of corresponding string in the byte array. this stores only the value of a single string.

Comment: @SachinKS, so you have to be more specific when you ask a question here. Look I have asked that 37 minutes ago as question comment

Comment: actually my string values are in the format of hexadecimal like 0 0 e4 8 d . every digits are in each line. i want to store corresponding byte values into each index of byte array....

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the getBytes() method from the String class :

```
str.getBytes()
```

Or if you don't use the default character set :

```
str.getBytes(myCharSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use,

**str.getBytes()** which will convert the string into the byte array.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code.

```
fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/s.hussain/Desktop/test3.txt");


          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          byte[] bytes = null;
          String str;
          int i=0;

          while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) 
          {

              bytes  = str.getBytes();
              i++;
              System.out.println(bytes.length);
          }

          in.close();
```

Comment: actually my string values are in the format of hexadecimal like 0 0 e4 8 d . every digits are in each line.

Comment: please give any sample line to parse.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html